# Is android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE needed when using android:installLocation="preferExternal"

Tags: android, permissions

My app is not yet published and since it is large I would like to use android:installLocation="preferExternal" in the manifest to allow the OS to install on external storage.
I also have an assets folder as part of the APK and I am using the AssetManager to access them from code.
Given these, do I need to add to the manifest android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: 
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/whats-changed-in-android-4-4-kitkat/ 
and a careful read of the docs here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

On versions earlier than KitKat (4.4) it is required to have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if external storage paths were read by the app (regardless if they come from calling Context or Environment methods). Since KitKat, the app gets its own "external" locations (which can in fact be either on the internal or the external storage if available) which are accessible without the need for permissions to read or write.